# Firebase user stored in localstorage doesn't work? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage

I'm saving the user object in localstorage upon creation (to be sure i can use it later inside a custom function, outside the authStateChanged):

```
const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
  promise.then(e => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    localStorage.setItem('fireUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    user.sendEmailVerification();
  }).catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

then i'm retrieving it inside my custom function below, it works when used like `user.uid` but it gives error "user.delete is not a function" when used as `user.delete()`, why is that? the variable `user` looks like this in the localStorage:

[image]

my custom function:

```
var myTimer;
function validTimer(timerValid){
  var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fireUser'));
  // var buser = firebase.auth().currentUser; <-- doesn't work here
  myTimer = setInterval(function() {
      timerValid++;
      localStorage.setItem('fireTimer', timerValid);
      if (timerValid == 22) {
        // delete in database
        var userId = user.uid;
        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
        ref.child(userId).once("value", function(snapshot){
          if (snapshot.exists()){
            database.ref("users/"+userId).remove();
          }
        });
        // delete account
        user.delete().then(function() {  // this says user.delete is not a function
        }).catch(function(error) {
        });
      }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: When u stringify an instance and then parse it back to an object, its stripped of its instance and therefore delete method.  I’m surprised your getting a null error.  Is that the actual error you get when you call the delete method?

Comment: @Vincent my bad the error actually is: "user.delete is not a function"

Comment: @Vincent The problem is i just tried to save it without JSON stringfy and parse, and it still throws the same error. So how am i supposed to store and retrieve it?

Answer (score 2):

It’s stripped of its instance methods when you stringify and parse it back.   The delete method is an instance method for a firebase user object.  In this case your user, although it looks the same, is not a firebase user. It’s just a bare object.

## Edit

For persisting the firebase user via the Client SDK, you want to use the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` method. Shortly after your page reloads, this method will fire. Set it here. Straight from the [web starting guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer Vincent! Correct on both counts: 1) since you serialize the `User` to JSON, which doesn't support methods, any methods of the `User` object are lost. 2) the proper approach is to simply attach an `onAuthStateChanged` listener in the place where you need the `User`. While the callback structure initially may seem weird, you'll get used to it eventually.

Comment: Doesn't "if (user)" work only if user has signed in? my timer function must work while user did not sign in. If i place the var to save current user in the "} else {" user returns null and doesn't work either

Comment: I knew of this authStateChanged thing as mentioned in my post, the problem is that if you reload the page the (user) is gone. What i'm trying to do is to save user upon creation and check with a timer if he verify, if not delete it. I thought was possible using localStorage and a timer..

Comment: You cannot delete a user with the client sdk if they are not signed in.  If your trying to store the firebase user so you can access it in other parts of your code,  set it globally on window or in some singleton class u can inject.  If your trying to only let the user sign in if they’ve verified their email, then as soon as they login, check the auth object for the emailVerified property. If it’s set, let them through, otherwise log them out and tell them to verify it. If this is the case, also log them out after you send the email.

Comment: @Vincent thanks for your time in advance, as you suggested i'm already letting users log if verified only, but I need to clean non verified users after few hours, or junk people will register 100 emails they don't own, is there a simply way to achieve that i'm not aware of perhaps? i think these basic anti-hack stuff should be built-in in firebase..

Comment: Firebase auth does have rate limiting. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits). As for purging bogus accounts, you certainly shouldn't/can't handle this in client side code. You'll want to run a cron job server side using the [admin auth api](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).